# How to bring 3D effect in google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, jsapi

In [google chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), for pie-chart it is easy to bring 3D view by just adding `'is3D':true`. But how we can able to get 3D effects for bar, column & combo charts, shown in this [demo](http://s3.amazonaws.com/nettuts/677_google/LiveDemo.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can find the 3D option in [Visualization: Column Chart (Old Version)](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old) and base on the [answer](http://goo.gl/ARscg).

Looks like the 3D option of column chart (and others) is not available with new version of `Core Charts`.

Comment: 3D option still not present in new ColumnChart

Comment: Still not there. And the direction is also not that, material Chart is available for Bar and Column charts (not for Combo yet). Such 3D is not part of material design, so I have a feeling that we won't see 3D.

Comment: This 3D feature is still not available as of Dec 2016.

Comment: yup...not yet! july 2017

Comment: Feb 2018, still not there

Comment: June 2021, most regretfully still not available

Comment: also not available in Nov 2022.

Answer (score 2):

```
is3D: true
```

does not work for Column Charts unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

also need to replace "corechart" by "columnchart"

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["columnchart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: 'columchart' instead of 'corechart' is the old version of the API.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following:

```
is3D: true
```

For example:

```
var options = {
    title: 'My Pie Chart',
    is3D: true
};
```

Comment: only works for pie charts